# dragging ccb file to the layer not working cocosbuilder

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

this should be a quick question, I was reading cocosbuilder tutorial [here](http://code.zynga.com/2012/10/creating-a-game-with-cocosbuilder/). I created a CCNode class and add some image animation to it, then I create a CCLayer class and wanted to add the node to the CCLayer class. Here's what it said on the tutorial "From the project view, drag the Dragon.ccb file to the canvas." But when I did, it's not showing up anything, it just creates a new CCNode class. Anyone knows what I did wrong? Thank you in advanced for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figure it out. I just didn't save the class.
 It's weird this way but if you want to save the class you created. You have to double click it first and save it manually. Just click the save option WILL NOT SAVE EVERY CLASS you created. So you have to go to each class and save each of them manually, I feel kinda lame this way...